# Como hacer cuadro de comentarios?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hola a todos mi pregunta es como puedo realizar un cuadro de comentarios como el que tenemos en este foro, con todas esas opciones que maneja con PHP, es posible?

gracias por sus respuestas
[image: Esto quiero lograr]

Comment: Quizás la pregunta es algo vaga... Posible, es, pero quieres saber COMO hacerlo, o bien, quieres un enlace que te diga como insertarlo en una web?

Comment: no creo que con php sea posible.. ya que funciona del lado de servidor.. lo puedes hacer con javascript

Comment: Hola a todos ya supe como implementarlo, generalmente son plugins javascript yo me decidi por este, esta muy completo CKEditor jaja  este es el link https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5-builds/